# swift storyboard screen not equal phone screen, XS MAX

Tags: swift, xcode

Having a hard time finding an answer for this.

The storyboard doesn't have the "view as" option for my iphone (xs max), so the screen on the storyboard always ends up butchered when i launch the app (the labels dont end up as they're seen in the swift storyboard). Am i missing something really simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I don't have the XS Max as a selectable "view as" option either. However, the reason you're having this issue is because of something called Autolayout. Autolayout allows you to set constraints for all your UI elements, keeping the UI's integrity across multiple devices. If you set constraints for each element on the screen, you'll solve this issue.

If you're unfamiliar w/Autolayout, learn more [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=emojd8GFB0o)